# how do i access clipboard

Tags: android, clipboard

How do I access the clipboard on HTC hero?

Comment: is that an android phone? windows mobile? more info / tags needed.

Answer (score 3):

I am not a developer for that platform, but Bing search returned this nice API reference:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/ClipboardManager.html